# BindingResolutionException with all response() calls in 7.x

Tags: laravel, lumen

- Lumen Version: 7.1.2
- Laravel Version: 7.12.0 (happens with all 7.x versions)
- PHP Version: 7.4.6
- Database Driver & Version: mysqlnd 7.4.6

#### Description:

All routes return error:

```
Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException: Target [Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollectionInterface] is not instantiable while building [Illuminate\Routing\Redirector, Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator]. in /home/harold/projects/work/git/sugar-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:1011
```

Routes work fine with Lumen 6.x, but appear to have problems with the changes to the class `Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator` from Laravel 7.12.0.

#### Steps To Reproduce:

Fresh install, then I have a route whose controller simply responds: `return response()->json($model)`.

The AppServiceProvider.php has the following [as instructed here for Lumen](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/pull/532), and it's `Illuminate\Routing\Redirector`  that loads the `Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator`:

```
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\ResponseFactory', function ($app) {
            return new \Illuminate\Routing\ResponseFactory(
                $app['Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory'],
                $app['Illuminate\Routing\Redirector']
            );
        });
    }
```